# Matchmol for substructure determination

Tags: cheminformatics

I'm using Checkmol/Matchmol for substructure determination and retrieval, and I'm having problems determining whether a given molecule is the substructure of another molecule when they have the same connectivity map.

I work in drug design so charges, isotopes, radicals and geometry are a very important concern.

Given the following molecules, for example:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
| mol_id  | formula         | smiles                              |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
|    7959 | C7H15Cl2N2O2P   | ClCCN(P1(=O)NCCCO1)CCCl             |
|   41041 | C7H15Cl2N2O2P   | ClCCN([P+]1([O-])NCCCO1)CCCl        |
|  572776 | C7H15Cl2N2O2P   | ClCCN([P@]1(=O)NCCCO1)CCCl          |
|  572791 | C7H15Cl2N2O2P   | ClCCN([P@@]1(=O)NCCCO1)CCCl         |
| 1742146 | C7H13Cl2D2N2O2P | ClCCN(P1(=O)NCC(CO1)([2H])[2H])CCCl |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
```

You can see that connectivity map is identical in all cases, though some variations in stereochemistry, charges and isotopes can be found:

[image]

First question: "subestrcture" is a very wide term but I think about it as to whether is molecule A contained in molecule B, or not. Would you say all these are substructures of each other given they share the same connectivity map?

In a practical scenario, ignoring charges, isotopes and stereochemistry, every molecule in the example will be a substructure of eachother:

```
matchmol someMol.sdf someOtherMols.sdf
```

According to matchmol help (which is the only documentation on matchmol usage I could find), adding the isotopes constraint (-i) would exclude 1742146; adding charges constraint (-a) would exclude 41041; and adding geometry constraints (-gG) would exclude both 572776 and 572791... or that is what I would expect.

However, running the program for each molecule using all constraints results in the following:

```
matchmol -sGgaid someMol.sdf someOtherMols.sdf
```

- 7959  7959    T
- 7959  41041   F
- 7959  572776  T
- 7959  572791  T
- 7959  1742146 F
- 41041 7959    T
- 41041 41041   F
- 41041 572776  T
- 41041 572791  T
- 41041 1742146 F
- 572776    7959    T
- 572776    41041   F
- 572776    572776  T
- 572776    572791  T
- 572776    1742146 F
- 572791    7959    T
- 572791    41041   F
- 572791    572776  T
- 572791    572791  T
- 572791    1742146 F
- 1742146   7959    F
- 1742146   41041   F
- 1742146   572776  F
- 1742146   572791  F
- 1742146   1742146 T

Notice that, as expected, for the plain molecule (7959), neither 41041 (charged) nor 1742146 (with D isotopes) are a substructure; but both stereoisomers (572776 and 572791) are.

Interestingly, for the the charged molecule (41041), the same molecule is a substructure (bug?), but plain and stereo are.

Stereoisomers 572776 and 572791 should not be substructure of each other when geometrical constraints are in place, yet they are...

So... second question: Am I doing something wrong? Am I misunderstanding the results?